# Recovering program from Android device

Tags: android, eclipse, recover

Ive written a program for my android device and its installed and working on my phone (S3), BUT ive just lost my PC HD and thought id saved my eclipse android coding folder but I didn't, the program is only a small one but took me a while to perfect so i need to recover it into eclipse to edit it more and save it.

Any ideas?

Cheers people
Mark

Comment: My Sympathies, I know this is a little late, but for future reference, I would move my `workplaces` project into the cloud service like Dropbox, Google Drive or Sky Drive. This way you project is always saved and backuped.

Comment: I know mate, i have a NAS server that backs up weekly BUT stupidly i wrote this in the last week BEFORE the backup ran grr, this is a BIG lesson learned

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is since you still have the **working** app on your S3, you can use something like

1. Use ES File Explorer to back up the app and retrieve the .apk file.
2. Decompile using: http://www.decompileandroid.com/, or [APK Tool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1989533)